# The return value of a LPCSTR function becomes trashy

Tags: c++, string, function, lpcstr

I was coding a simple XOR encryption program and then I noticed that the return value of a function is not the kind I expect to see.

I just can't find a problem in my code, could anyone help me?

Here's the program code:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;


LPCSTR hasala(string original, char key){

  string changed;

  for (int temp = 0; temp < original.size(); temp++){
  changed += original[temp] ^ (int(key) + temp) % 255;
  }

  cout << changed.c_str()<<"\n\n";//works, output "acagaca"

  LPCSTR adart = changed.c_str();

  cout << adart<<"\n\n";//works, output "acagaca"

  return adart;

}

int main(){

    cout << hasala("abcdefg", 0);//doesn't work, output "||||@ER|||"...

    cout << "\n\n";

    Sleep(8000);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer that you have is to memory owned by the `std::string` on the stack - when the `std::string` goes out of scope, it frees it, and then you read it. You must return `std::string`, not `LPCSTR`.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning `changed.c_str()` , which is just a pointer into the buffer managed by `changed`. `changed` is a local variable, and is destroyed when the function ends, so you're ending up returning a pointer to something that no longer exists.

Return the std::string `changed` directly.

Answer (score 1):

you are returning a local variable allocated on stack.

basically your code translate to:

```
LPCSTR hasala(string original, char key){
string changed;
return changed.c_str();
}
```

either allocate the memory (caller must free it) or return a std::string